# shortcode executed in the page editor

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode

I am trying to create a really simple plugin that creates a really simple shortcode, but when I insert the shortcode in the editor, and try to save the page I get the following error: "Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response."

I think the shortcode is being executed in the editor, because if I delete the shortcode there is no error, and I can see the echoed text for a second, when I opening the editor.

this is my plugin content:

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: test plugin shorcode
 */

function vbshort_shortcode() {
    echo 'Hello shotcode!';
}

add_shortcode('vbshort', 'vbshort_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`add_shortcode()` docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/):

> Note that the function called by the shortcode should *never* produce an output of any kind. Shortcode functions should *return* the text that is to be used to replace the shortcode. Producing the output directly will lead to unexpected results.

Your code should be:

```
function vbshort_shortcode() {
    return 'Hello shotcode!';
}

add_shortcode('vbshort', 'vbshort_shortcode');
```